# E: Package 'openswan' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, software-installation, openswan

I am on Ubuntu MATE 14.10, I have all my software sources turned on in 'Software & Updates', I have run `apt-get update`, etc, but I am still getting the following error when I run `sudo apt-get install openswan`:

```
E: Package 'openswan' has no installation candidate
```

How do I install `openswan`?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: On 15.04 I have the same problem.   `apt-get update` gives:  http://pastie.org/10263388

Answer (score 3):

You can fork the repo directly from Git repository. Then cd into your forked repo

```
git clone https://github.com/xelerance/Openswan.git fordername
```

To use Openswan with the linux native (builtin) IPsec stack, make programs:

```
sudo make install
```

To use the Openswan KLIPS IPsec stack (ipsec0 devices) for Linux
Kernels 2.6.23 and higher, make programs

```
make KERNELSRC=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build module
sudo make KERNELSRC=/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build install minstall
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `git` in your terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git
   ```
2. clone openswan:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/xelerance/Openswan.git
   ```
3. give permission:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x Openswan/
   ```
4. build linux:

   ```
   sudo Openswan/buildlin.sh
   ```